# Reading packet from serial port

Tags: c#, format, serial-port, pyserial

I'm reading a packet from a serial port. The packet has a one byte 0x7E flag sequence at the beginning and end of the packet. I'm using this code to read the packet from the serial port:

```
private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[serialPort.BytesToRead];
            int count = serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, serialPort.BytesToRead);

            dataIN = ByteArrayToString(buffer);

            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayData));
        }            
    }
```

I usually get the whole packet all at once. The problem is sometimes the packet is broken up. This messes up my whole code and breaks it. I was wondering is there a easy fix for this?

Comment: Yes, dont invoke until you have a full packet.

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont know the rest of your code I guessed something together, modify as needed. If you already employ flags, why not use them?

```cs
private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte lastByte = 0
        ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        while (lastByte != 0x7E || serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            int lastByte = serialPort.ReadByte()
            if (lastByte != 0x7E)
                dataIN += ascii.GetString(lastByte)
        }    
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayData));        
    }
```